# while converting linked list to number value error raising

Tags: python, list, while-loop, linked-list, numbers

i have a question that i want to convert a linked list to single number
for eg.,

```
assert 120 == list_to_number([1,2,0])
assert -120 == list_to_number([-1,-2,0])
assert 0 == list_to_number([0])
```

here i wrote a code for this but it is encountering an error

```
def list_to_number(head):
    p = True
    num = ''
    while (head!=None):
        val = str(head)
        if (val.find('-') == 0):
             p = False
        num = num + val.replace('-','')
        head = head.next
    if (p == False):
         return -1*int(num)
    else:
         return int(num)
```

therefore the error is

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird little function lol, but here you go

```
def list_to_number(head):
    p = True
    final_number = ''
    for number in head:
        n = number if number > 0 else -number
        final_number = int(str(final_number) + str(n))

    return final_number if p else -final_number
```

Comment: it is giving the error node object is not iterable here head means linked list node is not getting iterated @David Ludwig